# Errors with google map in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, mapactivity

I got this error from log cat, I know this error is very common from what I search from google but I still can not fix it, is there anyone can help me?

```
03-16 01:41:45.760: D/memalloc(23825): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54c92000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:80
03-16 01:41:45.770: I/MapActivity(23825): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
03-16 01:41:45.770: E/MapActivity(23825): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Comment: Can you provide your code..

Answer (score 0):

This exception will occur mostly because of missing permission.Please Check your manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And also in google liberary.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```